# iOs Web view how to make static a dynamic page

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

I have an iOs web View App wich connect to a touch responsive website and I would like to do some tabs in the app, one for contact form, another one for "about us", something like that... 
The problem is you can navigate to the main web site page from those tabs by pressing the top logo page, and I would like to invalidate that from x-code without editing the word press template. Basically I would like those tabs to be "static pages". Any one has an idea on how to do that or if it's posible to do it from x-code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UIWebViewDelegate`'s `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` method to check the URL your web view is trying to load. If URL is not one of the pages you want to allow access to, return `false`.